# Packaging code sign certificate - windows UWP app - not distributed through Microsoft store

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing-certificate

Need help on how to package code sign certificate with webapp developed in visual studio. 
The application setup/installer will be available for download on public website, so we plan to code sign it so it is smoothly installed on client PC. 
(1)

1. how to package code sign certificate
2. where to get code sign
       certificate at reasonable rate
3. current focus is windows
           platform, in future, we need to prepare installer for other
           platforms too (Apple, Linux ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can check comodo code signing certificate